# How to remove zoom information from a PDF bookmark

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have a PDF file with bookmarks (aka index and document outline), which seem to specify the zoom in which the document is displayed after the link is followed.  I know this because when I view the file in Evince and click on a bookmark, Evince automatically changes the zoom level.

Although this is documented in ISO 32000-1:2008 (Section 12), I don't like this behavior.  I want my PDF viewer to display the document in the same zoom level after using bookmarks.

A relatively new key `allow-links-change-zoom` in dconf is supposed to remedy this problem.  However, even after setting the key to `false`, Evince continued to show the previous behavior.  (Perhaps I might have needed to reboot the computer; but I can't check this because I don't have access to a newer version of Evince right now.)

That is why I've been trying to remove the zoom information from the bookmarks of the PDF file.

Keywords like `/XYZ`, `/Fit` and `GoTo` that appear in the specification does not occur in the file.  Perhaps the bookmark is encoded somehow.  So erasing the data by hand or by `sed` doesn't seem to work.

How can I do the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to uncompress the file using `pdftk` to actually be able to find the destination keywords.

If you still have a copy of the v1.7 PDF standard, you can also check section 8.2 for more details about the syntax. The section about named destinations might be of help.

Here is a little script I use for stripping the zoom factors from bookmarks in PDFs:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# decrypt the file
pdftk "$1" output decrypted.pdf && \
pdftk decrypted.pdf output uncompressed.pdf uncompress && \
# remove zoom factors in bookmarks
sed 's#/Fit#/XYZ#g' uncompressed.pdf > uncompressed_output.pdf && \
# compress the output
pdftk uncompressed_output.pdf output output.pdf compress && \
mv "$1" "$1.original" && \
mv output.pdf "$1" && \
rm decrypted.pdf uncompressed.pdf uncompressed_output.pdf
```

Save this to a file `removezoom.sh` and make it executable. You can then  call it as

```
~$ ./removezoom.sh yourFile.pdf
```

**Edit:** Ah, sorry, I was referring to section 8.2 in the document formatted by Adobe, named "PDF Reference, sixth edition". The formatting is different from the original ISO document, or so [Library of Congress claims](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000277.shtml).